# asm compile issue

Tags: assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly, addressing-mode

```
:96: Error: `(%rax,%edx,4)' is not a valid base/index expression

:97: Error: `-4(%rax,%edx,4)' is not a valid base/index expression

101: Error: `(%rax,%edx,4)' is not a valid base/index expression

102: Error: `-4(%rax,%edx,4)' is not a valid base/index expression
```

i get these error messages not sure how to fix it this is my code

```
                 "movl        $0, %6\n"
     line96      "start:        \n\t"
     line97      "movl        (%1,%3,4),%4\n\t"       
                 "movl        -4(%1, %3, 4), %5\n\t"  
             "cmpl        %4, %5\n\t"    
    line 101     "jle             next\n\t"
     line102     xchgl        %4, %5\n\t"               
                 "movl        %4, (%1, %3, 4)\n\t"        
                 "movl        %5, -4(%1, %3, 4)\n\t"        
                 "movl        $1, %6\n\t"
```

... my code is long so i did not want to post the whole code but i am doing a bubble sort in asm ,, when i compile i get the above error messages am not quite sure how to fix it ... if any one could  explain to what is wrong  will be helpful .. thanks .. sorry if the format is a bit untidy  am new to this ..

Comment: you could at least try to format your question nicely.

Comment: Please spent 30 seconds to format your code.

Comment: why do you list c if this is asm?

Comment: What assembler are you using? Looks like `gas`.

Comment: am sorry new to this ...........

Comment: i'll try to reformat it  , and @hotgan i tagged c because the program is in c with parts of asm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've incorrectly use indirect addressing.

It is incorrectly use ax:dx pair as base pointers with displacement. Refer to [this](http://simon.baymoo.org/universe/tools/symset/symset.txt) and [this](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404s2-03/addr_modes/intel_addr.html#HEADING2-73) for examples.

Comment: %rax and %rdx are valid registers for either the base or index of a 64-bit addressing mode.  Your last link is about 16-bit, which [doesn't allow a SIB byte so it much more restricted in which registers you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657904/why-dont-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes-have-a-scale-factor-while-the-32-bit-vers).  The actual problem here is that both registers have to be the same size if you use two in one addressing mode.  (And should match the mode, unless you explicitly want to truncate the address to 32-bit.  i.e. use RDX, not RAX.)